# Rename two columns in netezza using single query

Tags: multiple-columns, rename, netezza, alter

I am new to netezza. I need to know how can we rename two columns with a single query.

I've tried ,

```
ALTER TABLE tabemp RENAME COLUMN salary to empsalary and name to empname;

ALTER TABLE tabemp RENAME COLUMN salary to empsalary , name to empname;
```

But none of these is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a query, only one column can be renamed at a time. You can write a wrapper script to rename multiple columns or use IBM Netezza Performance portal to edit the table. Check the link [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.portal.doc/t_portal_edit_table.html?lang=en)!

Answer (score 1):

You can only rename one column at a time with ALTER TABLE.

[From the documentation, which can be found at this link,](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_alter_table.html?lang=en) you can see that ADD COLUMN is the only action which allows multiple specifications:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> <action> [ORGANIZE ON {(<columns>) | NONE}]

Where <action> can be one of:

ADD COLUMN <col> <type> [<col_constraint>][,…] |  

ADD <table_constraint> |  

ALTER [COLUMN] <col> { SET DEFAULT <value> |  DROP DEFAULT } |  

DROP [COLUMN] column_name[,column_name…] {CASCADE | RESTRICT } |  

DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> {CASCADE | RESTRICT} | 

MODIFY COLUMN (<col> VARCHAR(<maxsize>)) |  

OWNER TO <user_name> | 

RENAME [COLUMN] <col> TO <new_col_name> | 

RENAME TO <new_table> |  

SET PRIVILEGES TO <table>
```